# Randomly subset each group to satisfy conditions

Tags: r, for-loop, while-loop, dplyr

Looking to reduce resource allocation by looping through each resource's name, and looking at the assigned accounts to that persons name, selecting one at random and replacing that person's name with NA.

reproducible example:

```
Accts <- paste0("Acc", 1:200)
Value <- c(500, 2000, 5000, 1000)
AccountDF <- data.frame(Accts, Value)
AccountDF$Owner[1:200] <- NA
AccountDF$Owner[1:23] <- "Jeff"
AccountDF$Owner[24:37] <- "Alex"
AccountDF$Owner[38:61] <- "Steph"
AccountDF$Owner[62:111] <- "Matt"
AccountDF$Owner[112:141] <- "David"

library(dplyr)
OwnerDF <- AccountDF %>%
  group_by(Owner) %>%
  summarise(Count = n(),
            TotalValue = sum(Value)) %>%
  filter(!is.na(Owner))
```

Where I got so far:

```
for (p in 1:nrow(OwnerDF)){
  while (AccountDF$Count[p] > 22){
    AccountDF %>%
      filter(Owner == OwnerDF$Owner[p]) %>%
      sample_n(1)


  }
}
```

I've heard that for loops are unnecessary. I'm sure this can be done with the purr package and pmap or something like that. I am still learning.

I would like to iterate through the OwnerDF and look at whether that person "owns" too many accounts. If yes, look at the original account list and select a random one and replace the owner's name with NA, remove 1 from their count, and continue on.

Lastly after figuring this out I would like to see if it can be done with multiple conditions.. like While(Count > 22 & Value > $40,000), or maybe two while loops. The object is to reduce each person's "owned" accounts to less than a certain threshold and reduce $$ to less than a certain threshold.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To select random accounts, just make a random var and sort on it, taking the first N accounts that meet your conditions:

```
 set.seed(1)
 res = AccountDF %>% 
   mutate(r = runif(n())) %>% 
   arrange(r) %>% 
   group_by(Owner) %>% 
   mutate(newOwner = replace(Owner, cumsum(Value) > 40000 | row_number() > 22, NA)) %>% 
   select(-r)

# Test that it worked...
res %>%
  filter(!is.na(newOwner)) %>%
  group_by(newOwner) %>%
  summarise(Count = n(), TotalValue = sum(Value))

# A tibble: 5 x 3
#   newOwner Count TotalValue
#      <chr> <int>      <dbl>
# 1     Alex    14      27000
# 2    David    18      37000
# 3     Jeff    18      39500
# 4     Matt    18      39500
# 5    Steph    17      36500
```

---

An extension mentioned by the OP in a comment:

> Another question for you. Say I have a threshold for each value and count, and if someone has a low count but high value, I want to take a random account from their high value accounts, if they have a high count and low value, I want to take low value accounts away from them. How can I do this from a random perspective?

I'd probably assign a real-valued score to each observation, like...

```
s = scale(f(x))
```

where `f` is some function based on the conditions you mentioned (high count, high value or both), maybe as simple as `x` when you want to bias towards the low values and `-x` when you want to bias towards the high values.

Then, add on some noise and sort using the result as above:

```
r = s + rnorm(length(s))
```

Comment: Amazing. Thanks so much Frank. Worked perfectly. I never would have thought of a solution like that. I don't know much about random generation. 

Another question for you. Say I have a threshold for each value and count, and if someone has a low count but high value, I want to take a random account from their high value accounts, if they have a high count and low value, I want to take low value accounts away from them. How can I do this from a random perspective?

Comment: @MattW. Interesting question. You'd almost certainly want to roll a custom function to handle that. I added some to the answer about it.

Comment: You lost me a bit with that last part of your explanation haha. 

Also - I tried applying your solution to my data set and I cant get it to work. It breaks apart with the mutate replace. I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: @MattW. If you have missing values in `Value`, that might break it. Otherwise, nothing comes to mind. The basic idea is: assign a score to sort by, but add some noise before sorting since you want "high value accounts" not "the highest value account" (or at least it sounded that way).

Comment: I just checked, I don't have any missing values in Value. I can't figure it out. It's not throwing an error either. It's executing but the NewOwner field isn't coming up.

Comment: @MattW. Huh. I'm stumped. Not really a heavy dplyr user, so I guess it could be something I'm not seeing there.

Comment: I figured it out. *facepalm* The "NewOwner" column I was mutating, I actually happened to have that as a column already, so it was just updating a previous column and I didn't notice it because the df has 60 columns.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134998/discussion-between-matt-w-and-frank).